# How do I add "-------" under amounts in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am wondering how I can add the "-------" lines that can be seen in the photo under the amounts. I have tried various codes, but they all come back as an error. [image: Photo Here]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just something like `print("        ------")`

Comment: Please include the code you're using to print the rest. If you can code that I'm sure this would be a simple solution

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this `print("        ------")`

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to help you by using just the top of the table.

For more information you can go to [pyformat.info](https://pyformat.info/#string_pad_align).

If you would print the top of the table you would start with something similar with the code below, this is before trying any kind of format.

```
print("Ticket Order")
print("="*30)
print("Nr items:   60")
print("Price: (-20%) $ 1.20")
print("-" * 6)
```

Then for the formatting you can use the placeholders `{:}` with the formatting inside,
you can use the signs `<` for left alignment, `>` for right and `^` for center.
Then you should define a value that your information should be padded to a specific length.
So the expression will be: `{:'sign''length'}`. After use `.formating(str1, str2,...)`.

```
print("{0:^30}".format("Ticket Order"))  # align center ^
print("="*30)
print("{:<0}{:>21}".format("Nr items:", "60"))  # align right >
print("{}{:>17}".format("Price: (-20%)", "$ 1.20"))
print("{:>30}".format("-" * 6))
```

The final output should be:

```
         Ticket Order         
==============================
Nr items:                   60
Price: (-20%)           $ 1.20
                        ------
```